# How to figure out corrupted frame in a set of video frames(decode) using an open source library?

Tags: c++, media, decode, video-capture, video-processing

I am trying to figure out corrupted frame in a sequence of video frames. Please let me know if anyone is aware of some open source tool or any other tool or way to achieve this.
In corrupted frame i am looking as of now only green or blocky corruption.

Comment: Off topic if you are asking for a library. Too broad if you are asking about "how to achieve this".

Comment: @DevSolar Fully Agree.. Currently I am looking for a library to achieve this.

Comment: Asking for a library to do something is the one of the *definitions* of "off topic for StackOverflow", as it tends to attract opinionated answers and spam, and because there is no "correct" answer.

Comment: @DevSolar I have updated the query as per your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Please **do** read the following FAQ articles: [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) -- [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) -- [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Basically, SO is for helping with an *actual* problem you encountered while working with *actual* code. Your "green or blocky corruption" might not actually *be* a corruption of the video data, and anyway, telling you how to do video analysis is beyond the scope of a SO answer.